# Finding the area inside the polar equations $r = 2\sin(\theta)$ and $r = 1 - \cos(\theta)$

Tags: integration, area

Recently, I find it hard to find the area inside these 2 polar equations:

$$r=2\sin\theta\\r=1-\cos\theta$$

I  have found the intersection to be at $\theta = 127^{\circ}$ and $\theta = 0^{\circ}$.

I am very confused about what to do next. If someone could help me, that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Please format your mathematics using LaTeX.

Comment: Next step: sketch the region so you can work out lower and upper limits of $r$ between $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi$ and how the limits of $r$ changes at intersection point which you seem to have already found.

Comment: Is this not a case of doing the double integral with the bounds of $r$ depending on $\theta$, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of a polar curve bounded by the lines $\theta = \alpha$ and $\theta = \beta$, assuming that $(\alpha < \beta)\pmod{2\pi}$ is given by the integral $$A = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^{2}\,d\theta.$$

We are asked to find the area bounded by the polar curves $r = 2\sin\theta$ and $r = 1 - \cos\theta$.

As Claude Leibovici observed, the curves intersect at $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})$.

To get the area, we can integrate the first polar curve $(r_{1})$ from $\theta = \cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})$ to $\pi$

\begin{align*}A_{1} &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})}^{\pi}(2\sin\theta)^{2}\,d\theta \\
&= 4\int_{\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\theta\,d\theta \\ &=4\left(\frac{1}{2}(x - \sin x \cos x)\right)\bigg|_{\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})}^{\pi} \\ &=2(x-\sin x \cos x)\bigg|_{\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})}^{\pi} \\ A_{1} &=2(x-\sin x \cos x)\bigg|_{\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})}^{\pi} \\ &= 2(\pi - \sin \pi \cos \pi) - 2\left[\left(\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)\right) - \sin\left(\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)\right)\cos\left(\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)\right)\right] \\ &\approx 2\pi - 5.388594871\end{align*}

Then, integrating the second polar curve from $0$ to $\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})$,

\begin{align*}A_{2} &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{127}{180}\pi}(1 - \cos\theta)^{2}\,d\theta \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{127}{180}\pi} (1 - 2\cos\theta + \cos^{2}\theta)\,d\theta\end{align*}

This integral can be shown to be approximately $1.481446153$.

Adding both areas, we get approximately $2.376036589$.

---

Please recheck.

---

Edit: Claude Leibovici provided the correct angle, which is $\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})$ radians. The solution has changed.

Comment: isnt (2sintheta)^2 suppsoed to become 4sintheta^2. Sorry im very new to math stack exchange so i dont know how to format this.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, I didn't include that part as I 'factored' it out from the integral. Also, the intersection is at $\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5})$, not $127^{\circ}$ as @ClaudeLeibovici mentioned. Changing it now.

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates, the area is given by
$$A=\frac 12 \int r^2 \,d\theta$$ You have to integrate from $0$ to $\cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)$

So, these integrals being more than simple, you will have for the first curve
$$A_1=\frac{12}{25}+\cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)$$ and for the second
$$A_2=\frac{3}{4} \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)-\frac{23}{25}$$
$$A_1-A_2=\frac{7}{5}+\frac{1}{4} \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)=1.95357\cdots$$

Comment: for the second one, where do you integrate it from? is it from 135 to 180?